# Why do we to put templates in <app>/templates/<app>/blah.html, even though the default path is <app>/templtes/

Tags: django, templates, namespaces

According to the latest Django [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) for templates namaspace, we should put our templates in the order.

**app/templates/app/template_files**

But the default location it looks for templates is **app/templates/**, why not simply create a template file in templates sub-folder ?

> Template namespacing
>
> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for the application itself.

According to the explanation give in the documentation my approach would lead to ambiguity. so let's say we have two apps viz.
**app1 & app2** and they have index.html in **app/templates/** path, why can't django distinguish between two different path - /app1/templates/index.html & /app2/templates/index.html ?

Comment: Because this way you can override templates of other apps from a single app if you so desire. For example, there are some apps which provide separate admin templates. So those apps can keep the admin templates in `<app>/templates/admin/` and it's own templates in `<app>/templates/<app>/`.

Comment: sounds about right, i think unless i try the technique you mentioned i wouldn't able to understand it completely, anyway thanks for the explanation.